# Working on Class Objects for Python. Why is my Main() returning an error when a positional argument is given?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

**I'm doing an extra credit assignment for school. Here's the directions:**

### Create “Class” of Dog:

- Status (properties)

  - color = "yellow"
  - legs = 4
- Action (method):

  - Bark() – will take one string argument and print out follow by “Ruff Ruff”

On your main code, create two Objects: `Spot`, `Barney`

When you call this in your main code it should give the following results:

```
Spot = Dog()
Spot.bark("I'm Spot")
```

> I'm Spot : Ruff Ruff

```
print(Spot.color)
```

> yellow

```
Barney = Dog()
Barney.bark("Grrrrr")
```

> Grrrrr : Ruff Ruff*

So I completed the program, but when I put my two arguments into my "Main()" function, it says "Spot is not defined". I honestly can't think of where or why it should be defined. Do I have everything right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here's my code:**

```
class Dog:

    def _init_ (self, dog_name, color, legs):
        self.dog_name = dog_name
        self.color = yellow
        self.legs= 4

    def set_name(self, dog_name):
        self.dog_name = dog_name 

    def get_name (self):
        return self.dog_name

    def color (self):
        return self.color

    def legs(self):
        return legs

    def Bark(string):
        print(str(string) + " : " + "Ruff Ruff")

def Main (dog1, dog2):
    dog1 = Dog()
    dog2 = Dog()
    dog1.bark("I'm Spot")
    print(dog1.color)
    dog2.bark("Grrrrr")

Main(Spot, Barney)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of small things to fix here. First, make sure `_init_` is written as `__init__`. Second, provide default arguments to `color` and `legs`, rather than hardcoding them in `self.color = 'yellow'`.

The `bark` method is capitalized in one place but not others - keep that consistent. Also in the `bark` method, pass in `self` to keep it a method of `Dog`.

Lastly, and most importantly, the main method needs an overhaul. `Main(Spot, Barney)` passes in `Spot` and `Barney`, both of which are undefined variables. Even if they were defined, though, the main method overwrites the parameters it takes in:

```
def Main (dog1, dog2):
  dog1 = Dog()
  dog2 = Dog()
```

Here, don't pass any parameters into the main method. Rather, define `Spot` and `Barney` as instances of `Dog` in `Main()`. The final code should look something like:

```
class Dog:

  def __init__(self, dog_name, color="yellow", legs=4):
    self.dog_name = dog_name
    self.color = color
    self.legs = legs

  def set_name(self, dog_name):
    self.dog_name = dog_name 

  def get_name(self):
    return self.dog_name

  def color(self):
    return self.color

  def legs(self):
    return legs

  def bark(self, string):
    print(str(string) + " : " + "Ruff Ruff")

def Main():
  Spot = Dog("Spot")
  Barney = Dog("Barney")
  Spot.bark("I'm Spot")
  print(Spot.color)
  Barney.bark("Grrrrr")

Main()
```

Comment: I would also add a `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Had no idea that `__init__ ` had two underscores instead of one, so that definitely threw me off.

But glad to see I had most of it correct. At least I'm on the right track. Thanks again for your input.